# Preventing model window displaying on page refresh

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the Bootstrap modal to display details on button click window.
Now facing a problem whenever the page loading or refreshing the Model is also showing up. How can I prevent this from happening.?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function showPopup() {
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    }
</script>
```

### ASP

```
<section class="content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12" style="margin: 20px 0 20px;">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="box-header">
                    <h3 class="box-title">Orders</h3>
                </div>
                <!-- /.box-header -->
                <div class="box-body table-responsive ">
                    <asp:ListView ID="lvCustomers" runat="server" >
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table id="product-master" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <tr>
                    <th>Order #</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="groupPlaceHolder1"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <GroupTemplate>
            <tr>
                <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceHolder1"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            </tr>
        </GroupTemplate>
       <ItemTemplate>
            <td><%# Eval("OrderNo") %></td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="btnDetails" runat="server" Text="Products" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat" CommandName="ViewDetails" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("OrderNo")  %>' OnCommand="btnDetails_Command" />
        </ItemTemplate>

    </asp:ListView>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal fade modal-primary" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Products List</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="box-body table-responsive no-padding">
                    <%# Eval("OrderNo") %>
                     <asp:ListView ID="LvDetails" runat="server" GroupPlaceholderID="groupPlaceHolder1" ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceHolder1">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table id="products" class="table">
                <tr>
                    <th>Order #</th>
                </tr>
                <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="groupPlaceHolder1"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <GroupTemplate>
            <tr>
                <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceHolder1"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            </tr>
        </GroupTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <td><%# Eval("OrderNo") %></td>
            </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
                </div>
                <!-- /.box-body -->
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Done</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Could you please provide more info, Some code, a JSfiddle, a link to something, so that anyone can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure where is calling `.showPopup()`. That detail is important. But if its being called in any sort of `page_load` or anything that gets called from `page_load` then that would cause that problem.

Also if you're calling `.showPopup()` from some javascript code, then all javascript code gets run when the page is loaded/reloaded. You'd want to include some kind of conditional to make it call `.showPopup()` only when you need it to.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have something like this in your project?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    }); 
</script>
```

If so it might be the root of your issue, as this js function will set the modal to show on page load. You'll be able to find a lot simply by googling this issue as well.